# Pegar dados do retorno json em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tenho o seguinte JSON

```html
{
    "Result": [{
            "MatchKeys": "keyzs{78545}",
            "Relationships": {
                "Relationships": [{
                        "TaxIdNumber": "88548",
                        "StartDate": "2002-04-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "Date": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9944999"
                    },
                    {
                        "TaxIdNumber": "78548",
                        "StartDate": "2011-04-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "Date": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9339999"
                    },
                    {
                        "TaxIdNumber": "87548",
                        "StartDate": "2001-04-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "Date": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.99977999"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "QueryId": "b78f133f-e5bd-4123-8d34-7dd0faef0344",
            "ElapsedMilliseconds": 1226,
            "QueryDate": "2022-07-17T17:25:38.9599895Z",
            "Status": {
                "relationships": [{
                    "Code": 0,
                    "Message": "OK"
                }]
            },
            "Evidences": {

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Estou tentando retornar os dados que estão na chave Relationships mas quando estou tentando ele só retorna o primeiro item. Precisava pegar os seguintes dados da seguinte forma:


Usuario: 88548",

Data entrada: 2002-04-01T00:00:00Z",

Data Saida: 9999-12-31T23:59:59.9944999"


Usuario: 78548",

Data entrada: 2011-04-01T00:00:00Z",

Data Saida: 9999-12-31T23:59:59.9339999"

Usuario: 87548",

Data entrada: 2001-04-01T00:00:00Z",

Data Saida: 9999-12-31T23:59:59.99977999"

Já tentei e não consegui, gostaria de saber se poderiam me ajudar com o código para obter a listagem de dados.

Comment: Importante você [editar sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/559283/70) e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No caso você está trabalhando com JSON.

Para retornar as informações que você deseja precisaria usar um código assim:

```
<?php
$result = SEU_JSON_AQUI;
$JSONinArray = json_decode($result, true);

$Relationships = $JSONinArray['Result'][0]['Relationships']['Relationships'];

foreach($Relationships as $Relationship) {
    
    $TaxIdNumber = $Relationship['TaxIdNumber'];
    $StartDate = $Relationship['StartDate'];
    $Date = $Relationship['Date'];

    echo $TaxIdNumber . "<br />"
    echo $StartDate . "<br />"
    echo $Date . "<br /><br />";
}
```

Só um porém, eu passei o seu JSON do post em um validador e está dando erro. Não sei se pode ser um erro ou talves só um erro do editor, mas de qualquer forma vou deixar o link do validador onde você sempre pode passar o JSON para verificar se ele está correto:

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Validei o codigo json e deu valido , porem no resultado fica dando o erro

Comment: Warning: Undefined array key "Relationships" in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\validador.php on line 18

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\validador.php on line 18

Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\validador.php on line 20

Comment: Editei o código colocando um [0] após o result. Tente de novo

Comment: Consegui usando seu codigo muito obrigado meu amigo!